# Can a US citizen work remotely for a US company while studying in the Czech Republic on a student visa?

Tags: us-citizens, student-visa, employment, czech-republic

I am a US citizen wishing to study for my master's degree in the Czech Republic. I have BS in computer science, so I would almost definitely qualify as a skilled worked for a Blue Card if that would be helpful. I can work as either a traditional employee or a 1099.

Comment: Does your visa allow employment? Usually student visas don't allow employment or allow very limited employment options as part of internships or on campus.

Comment: For a blue card you have to be in an employment contract which makes a certain amount of money. Most student visas specifically do not allow for you to be working in the country (even if your employer is outside the country), which would mean you don't qualify for the blue card even if you do have a BSc.

In any case, check the terms of your student visa.

Answer (score 3):

There are three separate questions here:

- Are non-EU citizen students allowed to work in the Czech Republic? The answer is **yes**, you may work for as many hours as you want. See [this page](http://portal.mpsv.cz/sz/zahr_zam/zz_zamest_cizincu/zz_zvlastni) for proof:

  > No employment permit, Employee Card or Blue Card is required from a foreigner:
  >
  > who is systematically preparing for a future occupation in the territory of the Czech Republic
- Are non-EU citizens allowed to work for foreign companies? Absolutely, as long as they register as a self-employed person and pay taxes locally.
- Can you continue paying taxes back in the US? No, as a full-time student you will become a tax resident of Czech Republic and here is where most of the tax would be paid. I am aware that the US taxes its citizens worldwide, but luckily for you there exists a [tax treaty](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/international-businesses/czech-republic-tax-treaty-documents) between the US and Czech Republic, allowing you to deduct Czech taxes from whatever you owe to the US government.

Comment: Even without a tax treaty, US citizens and tax residents can use the Foreign Tax Credit to deduct foreign taxes paid on foreign-source income from any country, up to the amount of US taxes paid on that same income.